# Как получить координаты слоя (svg) в Photoshop?

Tags: svg, photoshop

Имеется ли возможность получить координаты определенного слоя в `Photoshop`(про сохранить в svg и далее извлечь из файла - знаю), чтобы далее применить их в `SVG` на сайте, например такого формата: `119 30,185 21,296 99,348 20,430 54,505 14,611 ...`

Comment: Svg - текстовый файл. Всё координаты внутри

Comment: `про сохранить в svg и далее извлечь из файла - знаю`

Comment: @MikeRo это очень плохая практика использовать растровый редактор для сохранения векторного файла svg/ Замаетесь потом, разбираться в путанице стилей после фотошопа. Освойте векторный редактор, например `Inlscape` Совсем не трудно интуитивно понять его принциры, да и уроков полно в инете.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT да, но макеты то в psd шлют, и там, в этих макетах есть svg. И есть целые схемы на все вкусы как их оттуда извлечь, и потом еще оптимизиорвать. Переводятся и сохраняются они в итоге в векторном редакторе. Думаю, автор это имел ввиду.

Comment: @kizoso я это и имел ввиду, потом такая каша. Или по тупому растр в base64 сохраняют, вроде вектор и не вектор, только оболочка, которая не стилизуется, и покрасить можно только через фильтры. Катя, да я знаю, что вы это всё лучше меня знаете :)  Дизайнеров надо посылать ... учиться вектору

Comment: @Alexandr_TT так я не использую Ps для вектора, просто он попался под руку в нужный момент... В Ps делал визуальную концепцию блока и решал сразу 'примерить' это в верстке, но т.к. с svg плохо знаком, пришлось задать глупый вопрос =)

Comment: @MikeRo плюс поставил за стремление разобраться в сложных вопросах. Хотя по началу показался очень вредным ваш вопрос по сути :)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT благодарю! =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Включите линейку <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>
2. Нажмите Moove Tool <kbd>v</kbd>
3. Нажмите в слоях на ваш слой и нажмите <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>
4. В панели инфо <kbd>F8</kbd> увидите ваши координаты по x и y.